# pagination implementation without database java

Tags: java, spring, pagination, spring-data, backend

I need to implement pagination in Java in SpringBoot application, but application stores data in memory (in HashMap), not in database, so I can't use Spring Data. I didn't find any examples how to do it, all examples only about pagination of data that stores in database when very easy to use spring PagingAndSortingRepositor but it's not my case.
I will be grateful for any help (ideas, code, links to resources).

Comment: How about database in memory like h2? or do you need to working only with hashmaps?

Comment: I have to work only with hashmaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [the Spring Data Key Value](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue) project. It provides the well-known Spring Data repository abstraction on top of key value pairs and provides a default implementation based on a `Map`.

You'd simply declare your repository to extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` and enable map-based repositories using `@EnableMapRepositories` on some configuration class.